# Custom navigation bar in every view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have two views, in the first i display the log in page which has a uiimage and i hide made the navigation bar translucent and in the second i have a collection view but when i scroll the navigation bar is still translucent so... i want it to be solid in the second view.
i put in the viewdidload from the second view this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

but when i go to the second view the uiimage of the first view is late to disappear.

what ca i do?

Answer (score 0):

on the first view

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

on the second view

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```